# How to give reference to Platform SDK from Groovy IntelliJ project?

Tags: groovy, intellij-13

I am new to Groovy and InteliJ. I need to create a project with Groovy script. It is dependent on Axeda platform SDK  from [here](http://developer.axeda.com/learn/by-type/product-documentation/sdk-javadocs)

Using intellij, I have created a New project - Groovy Module. Used project SDK as Java JDK 1.7

I need to import some classes from Axeda SDK now. How can I give the reference to this SDK now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the relevant .jar files from the SDK as [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).
Assuming you will need more than one .jar file and may need to reuse it for other project, you might want to create a global library for the SDK as described [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-project-and-global-libraries.html). Then you can use this library for any project which needs the SDK.